# Is there a tool to open a new page in Firefox in an already opened profile?

Tags: firefox, shell-scripting, netbeans

As far as I could determine, there is no native way to open a page in a Firefox multiple profiles environment when the profile is already open. On the Linux shell I am trying something like:

```
firefox -browser -new-window -P "development" http://google.com
```

No matter which arguments I add, I don't get around the message:

> Firefox is already running, but is not responding. To open a new window, you must first close the existing Firefox process, or restart your system.

It would be nice, if I could open a new window or even reuse a named one in a specified profile from an IDE, namely Netbeans 8.1, to debug some code.

Is there some tool, e.g. an addon, allowing me to do so?

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but with `-no-remote` ([at least on GNU/Linux](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Firefox_:_FAQs_:_Run_more_than_one_instance_in_Linux)) you can run instances from different profiles at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for your hint, just tried out. It does **not** get around the error message when the development profile is already in use. I guess it might be intended as a security feature not to be able hitchhiking some opened window and gathering informaion by other software. I can not see any other reason, why it isn't already implemented natively for a long time.

Answer (score -2):

Just use :

> firefox -P "development" http://google.com

Comment: It does not work when an instance of development profile is already open.